# insert a new element into array key in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array like this-

```
$array = array('o' => 'one', 't' => 'three', 'f' => 'four');
```

I want to add a new element in the 't' key of the array. The result will be like the following:

```
$array = array('o' => 'one', 't' => 'three','six', 'f' => 'four');
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Then there will be subarray in `t` key

Comment: And how would access it? you can use array inside array instead.

Comment: `$array['t'] .= ',six';` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it like that, For your target You have to use 2 dimension array, from other words array of array,

```
$array['t']=array('three','six');
```

and you can see the results like this,

```
Array ( [o] => one [t] => Array ( [0] => three [1] => six ) [f] => four );
```

You can easily access anything inside array using keys, if you want to access key "t",

```
$array['t'][0] = three and $array['t'][1] = six
```

This is the right way to solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is how i do it.

$array_for_t_key = ['three'];

$array = array('o' => 'one', 't' => $array_for_t_key, 'f' => 'four');

array_push($array_for_t_key,"six");

//Redeclare the array

$array = array('o' => 'one', 't' => $array_for_t_key, 'f' => 'four');